# Django email backend and smtp configuration

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-settings, django-email

I'm trying to use my Zoho account within my django project, in order to receive emails via contact forms.

I also followed this guide: https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/zoho-smtp.html

In the 'settings.py' file I wrote:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtppro.zoho.eu'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<domain name email>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<password>'
```

and in views.py:

```
def home(request):
    allTemplates = AllTemplates.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            body = {
                'name': form.cleaned_data['name'],
                'surname': form.cleaned_data['surname'],
                'from_email': form.cleaned_data['from_email'],
                'message': form.cleaned_data['message'],
            }
            mail_body = "\n".join(body.values())
        try:
            send_mail("Generic contact", mail_body, '<domain name email>',
                      ['<domain name email>'], fail_silently=False)
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Ops, qualcosa è andato storto')

    form = forms.ContactForm
    context = {'form': form, 'allTemplates': allTemplates,
               'allTemplates_length': len(allTemplates)}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

N.B. in 'send_email' I entered my email address twice to test

I also tried to use ssl

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtppro.zoho.eu'
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<domain name email>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<password>'
```

but nothing, I don't receive any email.

Is there anyone who has already gone through it or who can direct me towards some document or guide to study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use

```
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

1. my biggest pain was that all emails went to spam folder and I did not realize that for 2 hours.
2. test with local output to terminal:

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

3. test with local mail server to make sure the email is correctly created:

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='localhost' 
EMAIL_PORT=1025
```

and start local test mail server parallel to runserver in terminal window:

```
python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```