# Sending Email via Django Backend for forgeting Password

Tags: python, django, passwords

(Hello I'm working with Django for sending Email for forgeting password. I'm trying to use Django class based views to handle this forget password but, It was not worked properly. here is my code :

settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config("EHU")  # set my email 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =config("EHP") # set my app password
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.views import (
    LoginView, LogoutView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetConfirmView, PasswordResetCompleteView
)

from .models import UserAccount
from .forms import RegisterForm


class LoginPageView(LoginView):
    template_name = "login.html"
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return reverse_lazy("HOME")
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)


class LogoutPageView(LogoutView):
    template_name = "logout.html"


class SignupPageView(FormView):
    template_name = "register.html"
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("HOME")
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return reverse_lazy("HOME")
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_user = UserAccount.objects.create_user(
            email=form.cleaned_data['email'],
            username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
            first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            pic=form.cleaned_data['pic'],
            description=form.cleaned_data['description'],
            
            # TODO : If you add other fields to your model, include them here
        )
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PasswordChangePageView(PasswordResetView):
    template_name ="pass_change.html"
    email_template_name = "pass_change_email.html"
    subject_template_name = "password_reset_subject.txt"
    success_message ="""  We've emailed you instructions for setting your password,
                      if an account exists with the email you entered. You should receive them shortly.
                      If you don't receive an email,
                      please make sure you've entered the address you registered with, and check your spam folder. """
    success_url = reverse_lazy("HOME")


class PasswordResetConfirmViewPage(PasswordResetConfirmView):
    template_name = "password_reset_confirm.html"


class PasswordResetCompleteViewPage(PasswordResetCompleteView):
    template_name = "password_reset_complete.html"
```

The problem is when I try to test this with my admin credentials for forget password and enter my Email that I registered with it in the createsuperuser command, I didn't receive any email nor error.
can anyone help me out)

I figured out the previous problem and solved it ... but now There is another problem with "PasswordResetCompleteViewPage". In here when I send my new password to the server it throws 405 error. what happened to my server ? I'm using Linux Ubuntu 22.10 if it helps.

Comment: maybe this helps you to debug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75211512/django-email-backend-and-smtp-configuration/75211870#75211870

Comment: /usr/lib/python3.10/smtpd.py:106: DeprecationWarning: The asynchat module is deprecated and will be removed in Python 3.12. The recommended replacement is asyncio
  import asynchat"" I received this message and than the terminal stops there :(

Comment: it is only a warning - the server is waiting for mails and will print them on the terminal

Comment: Now I receive the 111 Error : [Errno 111] Connection refused ... I'm using ubuntu 22.10 machine, should I do something with my SMTP protocol?

Comment: when do you reseve the error? upon start of smtpd or when you try to send an email with you django appp and smtp.EmailBackend?

Comment: when I try to send the Email :(